# How can I explore a dictionary into a dictionary when im consuming an API. Example with PokeAPI

Tags: python, json, rest, dictionary

I'm trying to see the value of a key in a nested dictionary consuming an api. The code below iterate each pokemon in a the list of all pokemons and print some of its attributes. I know how to print the value of a single key like height, id, name or base_experience but how can I print the name of each ability?? for example:

JSON CODE

```
"id": 1,
"height": 7,
"name": "bulbasur",
"abilities": [
    {
      "ability": {
        "name": "overgrow",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/ability/65/"
      },
      "is_hidden": false,
      "slot": 1
    },
    {
      "ability": {
        "name": "chlorophyll",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/ability/34/"
      },
      "is_hidden": true,
      "slot": 3
    }
  ]
```

PYTHON CODE

```
import requests

def print_restul(json_respnse):
    pokemones = json_respnse.get("results")
    for pokemon in pokemones:
        # print(pokemon)
        explore_pokemon(pokemon)

def explore_pokemon(pokemon):
    url_pokemon = pokemon.get("url")
    r = requests.get(url_pokemon)
    json_respnse = r.json()
    # print(json_respnse.keys())
    print("el id del pokemon {} es {}, y la altura es de {}".format(pokemon.get("name"),json_respnse.get("id"),json_respnse.get("height"),))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    url = 'http://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon'
    r = requests.get(url)
    json_respnse = r.json()
    print_restul(json_respnse)

    for _ in range(10):
        print("== nuevo ciclo for === ")
        url_next = json_respnse.get("next")
        r = requests.get(url_next)
        json_respnse = r.json()
        print_restul(json_respnse)
```

Comment: Please paste the JSON as text, not a screenshot. And show an example of the output you're trying to get.

Comment: `for key, value in dictionary.items():`

Comment: `pokemones = json_respnse.get("results")`: I don't see a "results" key in your response.

Comment: @Barmar sorry, how I integrate that in the code??

Comment: When you have a dictionary that you want to print all the keys and values of, use `for key, value in dictionary.items(): print(f'{key}: {value}')`

Answer (score 0):

Loop over the `abilities` list and get all the names.

```
def explore_pokemon(pokemon):
    url_pokemon = pokemon.get("url")
    r = requests.get(url_pokemon)
    json_respnse = r.json()
    # print(json_respnse.keys())
    print("el id del pokemon {} es {}, y la altura es de {}".format(pokemon.get("name"),json_respnse.get("id"),json_respnse.get("height"),))
    abilities = ", ".join(a['ability']['name'] for a in json_response.get("abilities", []))
    print(f'abilities: {abilities}')
```

Answer (score 0):

In long run it might be a better idea to model your data as [dataclasses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) instead of python `dict` objects. It will also promote code quality and code reuse which I feel is a good idea in general.

To work with nested dataclass model and easily generate it from json, I suggest using [`wiz`](https://dataclass-wizard.readthedocs.io/en/latest/wiz_cli.html) command-line from dataclass-wizard. This library can be install with `pip install dataclass-wizard` and then you have access to `wiz` utility from a terminal to generate a nested dataclass schema.

In this scenario, your code now becomes like below:

```py
def explore_pokemon(pokemon):
    url_pokemon = pokemon.get("url")
    r = requests.get(url_pokemon)
    json_respnse = Data.from_dict(r.json())
    # print(json_respnse.keys())
    print("el id del pokemon {} es {}, y la altura es de {}".format(pokemon.get("name"),json_respnse.id,json_respnse.height),)
    abilities = ", ".join(a.ability.name for a in json_respnse.abilities)
    print(f'abilities: {abilities}')
```